# Detect keyup when PopupMenu is visible

Tags: android, popupmenu

I want to be able to select an option from a PopupMenu using keys (i.e. the numbers 1-4). The device I'm writing an app for has a built in numeric keypad, making them always accessible (not using soft keyboard).

The aim is for the user to be able to press a number/button and the menu will be shown, which is working, here (this is in my activity):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    Log.d("onKeyUp", KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode));
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5) {
        showPopupMenu((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu));
    }
    return true;
}
```

I would like to be able to then select one of the options from the menu using the key pad, however when the menu is visible, the onKeyUp event isn't fired whenever a key is pressed.

Here's the menu code:

```
public void showPopupMenu(View v){
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    final MenuInflater menuInflator = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            //Do something
            return true;
        }
    });

    menuInflator.inflate(R.menu.current_screen_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

This is using Android 4.1 (API 16). Thanks for any help! Happy to provide more code where needed.

Comment: Could you find a way to do that? I'm facing a similar problem!

Comment: Hey, sorry can't say I was able to get this working. I ended up getting around it by using a plain and simple 'Dialog' which you can find http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set keyevent listener in popupwindow object like this

```
public void showPopupMenu(View v){
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    final MenuInflater menuInflator = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            //Do something
            return true;
        }
    });

    menuInflator.inflate(R.menu.current_screen_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.show();

    // You have to implement following listner
    popupMenu.getContentView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {        
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && 
                    event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && 
                    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // ... payload action here. e.g. popupMenu.dismiss();
                return true;
            }                
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```